# ssh-keyscan does not read .ssh/config?

Tags: ssh, ssh-keys, known-hosts

I am using `ssh-keyscan` in a shell script to accept keys for hosts.  The hosts are identified by hostname but not in /etc/hosts.  They are in `./ssh/config` so I can `ssh <hostname>` but I can not `ping` etc.

It looks like `ssh-keyscan` is not using the `.ssh/config` file and that seems funny.

Can someone confirm this happens to them?

Real question: Does someone have a way to make ssh-keyscan use ~/.ssh/config?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ssh-keyscan doesn't and cannot be made to use `.ssh/config`.

However, what you are asking for doesn't require it to do so: Simply passing the real hostnames/addresses to ssh-keyscan (and thus storing them in the known_hosts) will work, even if you use the aliases from the config with `ssh`. But you can even instruct ssh-keyscan to add other names to the output besides those it used to connect when using the `-f` option:

```
 -f file
         Read hosts or “addrlist namelist” pairs from file, one per line.
         If - is supplied instead of a filename, ssh-keyscan will read
         hosts or “addrlist namelist” pairs from the standard input.
```

Comment: It's not an answer I wanted and it doesn't help me but I guess it is the correct answer.  Thank you.

Comment: If ssh-keyscan can't read ~/.ssh/config, then it can't (?) get keys from machines behind a jumpserver (e.g., using ProxyJump keyword, see `man ssh_config`). I justed that and got this result: `getaddrinfo foo.company.com: nodename nor servname provided, or not known`

Comment: For jump server set-ups, [here's a relevant solution](https://serverfault.com/a/823719/335080).

Answer (score 0):

ssh-keyscan is a utility for gathering the public ssh host keys of a number of hosts. It was designed to aid in building and verifying `**ssh_known_hosts**` files. ssh-keyscan provides a minimal interface suitable for use by shell and perl scripts.

```
-f file
Read hosts or addrlist namelist pairs from this file, one per line. If - is supplied instead of a filename, ssh-keyscan will read hosts or addrlist namelist pairs from the standard input.


Input format: 
1.2.3.4,1.2.4.4 name.my.domain,name,n.my.domain,n,1.2.3.4,1.2.4.4

Output format for rsa1 keys:
host-or-namelist bits exponent modulus

Output format for rsa and dsa keys:
host-or-namelist keytype base64-encoded-key

Where keytype is either ''ssh-rsa'' or ''ssh-dss''.
/etc/ssh/ssh_known_hosts
```

For Example:

```
Print the rsa host key for machine hostname:
$ ssh-keyscan hostname

Find all hosts from the file ssh_hosts which have new or different keys from those in the sorted file ssh_known_hosts:
$ ssh-keyscan -t rsa,dsa -f ssh_hosts | sort -u - ssh_known_hosts | diff ssh_known_hosts -
```